# Spring MVC Form - Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Why do I get "Request method 'GET' not supported" when I got to URL "http://localhost:8080/SpringTest3/addStudent.html"?

StudentController.java:

```
package com.springtest3;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView showStudent() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result/*, final ModelMap model*/) {
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
           System.out.println("ERROR ERROR ERROR");
       }

       /*model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
       model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
       model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());*/

       System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());

      return "redirect:students.html";
   }
}
```

addStudent.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="addStudent.html">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution:**
As suggested below I added this method in StudentController.java:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void test(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("student", new Student());       
   }
```

But I also need to change the following line in addStudent.jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addStudent.html">
```

to

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="student" action="addStudent.html">
```

Comment: I removed the XML code from this question, as the real meat of it doesn't lie in those.  It only lies with your controller, and from what I'm reading, you've got some great answers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you put http://localhost:8080/SpringTest3/addStudent.html in the url, a GET request is initiated. However, the addStudent method in your controller has

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

which filters to only allow POST requests to access this method.

In order to allow GET requests, change the Mapping for another addStudent method with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I added another addStudnet method with GET but then I get the following error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"

Answer (score 5):

> > Why do I get "Request method 'GET' not supported" when I got to URL "http://localhost:8080/SpringTest3/addStudent.html"

Because you have defined it to accept post method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And when you invoke it directly say via browser, you are accessing the resource using HTTP Get method.

If you change this to RequestMethod.GET, you would avoid the error you would see. But Post seems appropriate from what it means, does. So access it via form that you paste rather than from URL or to test it, use appropriate http client and set http method to POST.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What do you mean by: "So access it via form that you paste rather than from URL" @SMA

Comment: Like you did right? `form method="post" action=...`

Comment: I really don't get this. :) But how do I get to the page (addStudent.jsp) where I can fill in the form? Is it not possible to visit that page in a regular browser? @SMA

Comment: I would really appreciate the help! @SMA